# What function fires first when doing Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that is using Windows authentication.  I want to execute some code whenever a user starts a session on the site.  Is there any function that executes when the Windows authentication happens that I could add code to?

Answer (score 0):

I found this function in the Global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    // To what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax.cs has Application_AuthenticateRequest function:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 // Add your code here
}
```